# javascript click to expand the menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have below code html + javascript. It is the main page with left menu section.
In the left menu, i find that when i click the first level (profile_update_lv1), it does not expand the second level (profile_update_lv2). Do you have any ideas?? Is it because of browser-compatible or anything code wrong??

```
<div id="profile_update_lv1" class="div_lv1"><input id="profile_update_btn_status" type="hidden" value="0"><a href="javascript:" onclick="buttonClick('profile_update_lv2','profile_update_btn_status'); " onmouseover="MM_swapImage('btn_profile','','/awip_strut2_tiles_serialize_dac/images/membersite/zh/menu_profile_update_r.gif',1);" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="http://localhost:7001/awip_strut2_tiles_serialize_dac/images/membersite/zh/menu_profile_update.gif" name="btn_profile" width="175" height="24" border="0" id="btn_profile"></a>
        <div id="profile_update_lv2" class="div_lv2" align="right" style="display:none;">
            <div><a href="changePwd" class="nav_grey_B_11" id="CHANGEPW">Change password</a></div>                  
            <div><a href="changeEmail" class="nav_grey_B_11" id="CHANGE_EMAIL">Change email</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript1.2">
    var lastClick = "";
    var submenu = "";
    var lastClickStatus = "";

    function buttonClick(obj, status)
{
alert("buttonClick");
    if(document.getElementById(status).value ==0)
    {   
    alert("status=0");
        if(submenu!="") {
            $("#"+ submenu).slideUp();
            submenu="";
        }
        if(lastClick!="") {
            $("#"+ lastClick).slideUp();
            document.getElementById(lastClickStatus).value = 0;

        }
        alert("before slidedown");
            $("#"+ obj).slideDown();
        alert("after slidedown");
        document.getElementById(status).value = "1";
        lastClick = obj;
        lastClickStatus = status;
    }else{
        $("#"+ obj).slideUp();
        document.getElementById(status).value = "0";
    }   
}

    function buttonClickSub(obj, status) 
    {
        if(document.getElementById(status).value ==0)
        {
            $("#"+ obj).slideDown();
            document.getElementById(status).value = "1";
            submenu = obj;
        }else{
            $("#"+ obj).slideUp();
            document.getElementById(status).value = "0";
            submenu = "";
        }   
    }
    function openDisplay(obj){
        $("#"+ obj).show();
    }
    function cssOnGrey11(obj){
        $("#"+obj).removeClass("nav_grey_B_11");
        $("#"+obj).addClass("nav_grey_B_11_o");
    }
    function cssOnGrey10(obj){
        $("#"+obj).removeClass("nav_grey_B_10");
        $("#"+obj).addClass("nav_grey_B_10_o");
    }

    function highlightLv2(objId_lv1,objId_lv2,statusObjId)
    {
        document.getElementById(statusObjId).value = "1";
        openDisplay(objId_lv1);
        cssOnGrey11(objId_lv2);

    }
    function highlightLv3(objId)
    {
        cssOnGrey10(objId);
    }
    function parentRedirect(destUrl)
    {
        if (destUrl.substring(0,1) == "/")
        {
            destUrl = "http://"+getHost(document.location.href)+destUrl;
        }
        var newWin = window.open(destUrl);
        newWin.focus();
    }


    </script>
```

I have tried below code according to some advice from below: But it have no response when I click the `<p>click</p>`

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
            <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test").click(function()
  { 
    $(".toggle-div").slideToggle(),
    $(this).toggleClass("active"),
    $(".toggle-div  p").on("click",function(){$(".toggle-div").slideUp()})
  });
});
    </script>
    <style>
    .toggle-div{display:none;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        <div class="test">
          <p>click</p>
        </div>
        <div class="toggle-div">
           <p>hello</p>
        </div>
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: any error in your console

Comment: No error. But it seems refresh the whole page

Comment: try to replace `href="javascript:"` to `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: Sorry, I have replace to href="javascript:void(0)", still not working but this time the page would not refresh.

Comment: I have added alert to function buttonClick(). I find that "before slideDown" alert is shown, but not "after slidedown" alert shown. Anything wrong about slideDown() or slideUp()??

Comment: function buttonClick(obj, status)
{alert("buttonClick");
 if(document.getElementById(status).value ==0)
 { 
 alert("status=0");
  if(submenu!="") {
   $("#"+ submenu).slideUp();
   submenu="";
  }
  if(lastClick!="") {
   $("#"+ lastClick).slideUp();
   document.getElementById(lastClickStatus).value = 0;

  }
  alert("before slidedown");
   $("#"+ obj).slideDown();
  alert("after slidedown");
  document.getElementById(status).value = "1";
  lastClick = obj;
  lastClickStatus = status;
 }else{
  $("#"+ obj).slideUp();
  document.getElementById(status).value = "0";
 } 
}

Comment: It said "$" is undefined in line  $("#"+ obj).slideDown();??? What does it imply??

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery. It's a simple 4 to 5 line function. I have a updated code here you can review [example](https://jsfiddle.net/anmolsandal/pgxo166n/2/).

```
'https://jsfiddle.net/anmolsandal/pgxo166n/2/'
```

Comment: I have tried your code. It is not working after replace my code by yours. Is there any missing??

Comment: Checking it out, Was working yesterday. I will let you know asap.

Comment: Please go ahead. It has been updated. Link is updated too. i have used jquery here so you need add jquery plugin to run this.

Comment: Actually I have put <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.mi‌​n.js" ></script>
, but it still does not work. Is there any wrong of my code??

Comment: Url you have used for jquery library is not working. Use this one
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js

Comment: I have tried your example with my code posted above. It is still not working. Anything I am missing??